# Debug only your Android source in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, breakpoints

I set up a breakpoint in my code, and when I go into the debug mode it stops at the breakpoint.
When I step into or over, instead of going to the next line of my source code the debugger takes me into the SDK source code.

How can I avoid this and only view the debugging of source which I wrote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will happen when you step into code which you did not write (i.e. other dex bytecode), so you need to step over these lines. This will also happen if an exception is thrown, so be careful of that as well. Otherwise, it should work just fine.

Is there a specific issue you're running into?

Comment: I am just trying to debug only the code which I wrote. Even If I step over (F6 for Eclipse) I still end up going into the SDK code, and I may have to step over 100 lines of SDK code before getting back to my source.

Comment: This is correct, it did not get me straight back into my code, only because I kept on stepping through the code hoping to get back to my source.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set up Step Filtering in Eclipse
Preferences->Java->Debug->Step Filtering
And add the classes you want to ignore

Answer (score 0):

When you are in not your code - click "Step Return" (Arrow Up-Right) and you will return to your code.